# Is there any function to filter the field values based on another field value in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

**model1**

```
class Client(models.Model):
    
    client_name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    company=models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    finance_contact_email=models.EmailField(max_length=25,default=None)
    business_purpose=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True,default=None)
    location=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    emergency_contact=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,default=None)
    website=models.URLField(max_length=200,null=True)
    comments=models.TextField(max_length=300,null=True, blank=True)
    start_Date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=10,null=True)
    end_Date=models.DateField(max_length=10,null=True)
```

**Model2**

```
class Project(models.Model):
    
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    client= models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name="Client1",default=None)
    description=models.TextField()
    type=models.TextField()                                      
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    end_date=models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    technical_contact_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=254,default=None)
    phone = PhoneField(blank=True)
    delivery_head_contact_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**model3**

```
class Job(models.Model):
    
    job_name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    client=models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='client',default=None)
    project=models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='project',default=None)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='user',default=None)
    hours=models.TimeField(null=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    end_date=models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
```

Actually I need to filter the values based on the clients in the `Job` model. For example we will be giving the project_name on the `Project` model based on selecting the specific clients. So we need a filter in the `Job` model like if we select the specific client in the field, it needs to display only the projects available for that client in the project field of `Job` model.

Now it is displaying all the projects which are inputted. Please help me get this solved as I am new to django.

Comment: Can you give an example with values ? I don't quite get your formulating. If I correctly understood, you want to filter `Job` with the `project_name` field of `Project`, so filtering a base model through a relationship field ?

Comment: No, i will explain you, (ex 1: if client = Amazon and the project for that client is = App and another client = flipkart and the project for that client is = Web, in the Job model i need to get based on the client filters. Like if i select Amazon in the client it needs to give me only the projects available for Amazon, that is App.).Now it is returning the projects for all the clients.

Comment: What I don't understand is where you are trying to make the query, you want to return Project model but using the client field from a Job model. It feels like a Job should not have both client and project if project also have client. Isn't just querying the Project model with filter(client__name='Amazon') sufficient ?